# File Open Function with Try & Except Python 2.7.1

Tags: python, file, function, try-catch, except

```
def FileCheck(fn):       
       try:
           fn=open("TestFile.txt","U") 
       except IOError: 
           print "Error: File does not appear to exist."
       return 0
```

I'm trying to make a function that checks to see if a file exists and if doesn't then it should print the error message and return 0 . Why isn't this working???

Comment: Specify what you mean by "not working."

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You'll need to indent the return 0 if you want to return from within the except block.
Also, your argument isn't doing much of anything. Instead of assigning it the filehandle, I assume you want this function to be able to test any file? If not, you don't need any arguments.

```
def FileCheck(fn):
    try:
      open(fn, "r")
      return 1
    except IOError:
      print "Error: File does not appear to exist."
      return 0

result = FileCheck("testfile")
print result
```

Comment: To elaborate, the problem identified by OregonTrail is that your `return 0` is indented to the same level as your `if` statement. This puts the `return` outside the `if`, so the function returns `0` regardless of whether it got an error or not.

Comment: how do i call the function? do i need to set a file to a variable? if i did that it would just be opening the file . . .

Comment: I've added some lines to flesh out the example

Comment: This worked well for me. I used `f = open(fn, "r")`. However, when I used a `finally` block to close a file that does not exist, I got the error message `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'f' referenced before assignment`. I could only close the file successfully with an `else` block and not a `finally` block - I used `else: f.close()`.

Comment: ah, good point, try .. else is the way to go here for resiliant execution

Answer (score 5):

I think `os.path.isfile()` is better if you just want to "check" if a file exists since you do not need to actually open the file. Anyway, after open it is a considered best practice to close the file and examples above did not include this.

Comment: I like this better. Is there a version for checking a directory too?

Comment: isfile is definitely better. For plain files, it should be harmless to open files, but it can have unexpected side-effects if, for example, it's a named pipe. Also, when you leave the scope, the file should close automatically.

Answer (score 4):

This is likely because you want to open the file in read mode. 
Replace the "U" with "r".

Of course, you can use `os.path.isfile('filepath')` too.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to check if a file exists or not, the python os library has solutions for that such as `os.path.isfile('TestFile.txt')`. OregonTrails answer wouldn't work as you would still need to close the file in the end with a finally block but to do that you must store the file pointer in a variable outside the try and except block which defeats the whole purpose of your solution.