# How to open file using try except in python?

Tags: python

i have a txt file i would like to use in my program named animallog1.txt. How do i open it so that it can be used in my program using try and except.  I know how to use the file using open function but not using try except. Could someone tell me how it is done

Comment: 1. It is unclear what you are asking, but here is your possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380006/file-open-function-with-try-except-python-2-7-1 2. Try to put at least minimal research effort before asking such questions. `try-except` clause is a standard python combination and if you'd open docs you'll get the idea that you can't open file with try and except...

Comment: You can't open a file with `try...except`. I think what's being asked is to open the file like you usually would and catch exceptions if they occur using `try...except`.

Comment: Maybe this is what you want? http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/

Answer (score 12):

You're very vague, but I'll try and answer your question. The reason you use `try` and `except` is to catch an error. In opening a file you would get an `IOError`. So this is how you would open a file as such:

```
try:
    with open("file.txt","r") as f:
        #stuff goes here
except IOError:
    #do what you want if there is an error with the file opening
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Except is not a method of doing something. It's a way of handling errors. Check out [this page](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) for more info. Basically, if you think you're going to get an error, you put the code you think will produce an error in the `try`. Then, you put code you'd like to execute if the error does happen in the `except`.

For example:

```
try:
    a = int("apple")
except ValueError:
    a = "apple"
```

What is happening here is that in the try statement, the line produces a `ValueError`. It's caught in the except clause and the lines there are computed instead.

So, for you what I would recommend is:

```
try:
    f = open("test.txt", "r")
except IOError:    #This means that the file does not exist (or some other IOError)
    print "Oops, no file by that name"
```