# Copying files in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Ok well i have another question. I implemented the error checking but for some reason it still isn't working. I still get a python error instead of the error i just wrote in the program.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/python/copyfile.py", line 31, in <module>
    copyFile()
  File "E:/python/copyfile.py", line 8, in copyFile
    file1 = open(source,"r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Public/asdf.txt'
```

Comment: Just FYI, there is [shutil.copyfile(src, dst)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile).

Comment: So, what does your program do when you pass in an invalid filename?  That should give you an idea of what to look for as you attempt to read/write files.  Do you know how to implement exception-handling?  If not, do a quick Google on 'python exception handling' and see what you can come up with.  Good luck :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8380006/1579844

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    copyFile()
  File "E:/python/copyfile.py", line 6, in copyFile
    file1 = open(source,"r")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/Public/asdf.txt'

This is the error I get.

Comment: Alright I figured it out... thanks to you guys :) The problem was that I had my try and except statements all in the wrong places. With a quick move the problem was quickly resolved. Thank you guys again.

Comment: Please don't deface your question, now that you have received answers to it. Questions aren't just for the benefit of the asker, but for many visitors in the future.

Answer (score 9):

check out the `shutil` module in standard library:

```
shutil.copyfile(src, dst)
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile

Comment: I'm not allowed to use any built in functions. anyways, i got it updated... but apparently the check still isn't quite right..

Answer (score 1):

I would rather ask you to write your own:

```
import os
import hashlib

def md5ChkSum(_file):  # Calculates MD5 CheckSum
    with open(_file, 'rb') as fp:
        hash_obj = hashlib.md5()

        line = fp.readline()
        while line:
            hash_obj.update(line)
            line = fp.readline()
        return hash_obj.hexdigest()

def copier(_src, _dst):
    if not os.path.exists(_src):
        return False

    _src_fp = open(_src, "r")
    _dst_fp = open(_dst, "w")

    line = _src_fp.readline()
    while line:
        _dst_fp.write(line)
        line = _src_fp.readline()
    _src_fp.close()
    _dst_fp.close()

    if md5ChkSum(_src) == md5ChkSum(_dst):
        return "Copy: SUCCESSFUL"
    return "Copy: FAILED"

res = copier(r"/home/cnsiva/6.jpg", r"/home/cnsiva/6_copied.jpg")
if not res:
    print "FILE Does not Exists !!!"
else: print res
```

OUTPUT:

```
Copy: SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: @khachik, Does it make any trouble, here we are not stick to the stylings. Check for the Functionality !!!

Comment: for the functionality there is shutil, no need to reinvent it.

Comment: @khachik, the Question is not to use the `built-in` methods

Comment: `shutil` is not built-in and I don't see anything about built-ins in the question as well.

Comment: Check the comment on the other answer