# Download file on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have this simple function in my `Flask` app.

```
@app.route('/download')
@login_required
def download():
    url="some_random_video_url_here"
    re = requests.get(url)
    with open("download/hello.mp4", 'wb') as file: #save hello.mp4 to download folder
        file.write(re.content)
        file.close()
flash("done downloading.")
return render_template('download.html')
```

When I run the app locally, the download function just run fine. But when I deploy the code to `Heroku` and access the url, I get `500 Internal Server Error`

I think it has something to do with file system on `Heroku` but I don't know how to make this work. So how?

Comment: Does the download/ directory exist? Note that the Heroku filesystem is temporary (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

Comment: Can you post the Heroku log? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#view-logs

Comment: @elithrar yes, I included download folder in git push.

Comment: @fasouto 2015-07-09T22:27:36.092922+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/login?next=/download" host=discover-flask-again.herokuapp.com request_id=e270875b-ddc7-47d8-ab04-2cadd7c31797 fwd="85.165.229.223" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=29ms status=302 bytes=538

Comment: Can you wrap your `open` call in a try/except block (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8380019/556573) - otherwise there is no way to inspect what error (if any) is being returned.