# How to handle the exception when input file does not exists in python?

Tags: python, file, exception

Lets assume i have a file named 'student.csv'.But in my python,I have mistakenly passed 'student1.csv' as file input,which does not exist.How to handle this exception to stop the execution further.

Comment: Just letting the program crash with a FileNotFoundError seems like a perfectly fine way to handle the exception. Execution of the program is stopped, exactly as desired; and anyone reading the stack trace knows exactly what the problem is.

Comment: use try -except block

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Open Function with Try & Except Python 2.7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380006/file-open-function-with-try-except-python-2-7-1)

Comment: @Kevin: Sure, 'cause nothing breeds confidence in an end user than seeing a stack trace.

Comment: @Kevin, for example, `open(nonexistent_file, 'w')` doesn't raise an exception, but creating a new file may not be desired, so this behavior may be considered an "exception". It's hard to tell what "exception" means in this context because unhandled exceptions _do_ stop the program's execution, which somehow isn't the case here

Comment: I am getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
How to handle this exception

Comment: @ScottHunter Don't think of it as user-hostile design; think of it as encouraging the user to learn the fundamentals of programming. Having to diagnose uncaught exceptions builds character ;-)

Answer (score 10):

Here is a working example, if the file is not found it will throw and `FileNotFoundError` exception

```
try:
    f = open('student.csv')
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File does not exist')
finally:
    f.close()
    print("File Closed")
```

Another Way:

```
try:
    with open("student.csv") as f:
        print("I will do some Magic with this")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('File does not exist')
```

Also If you dont want custom error message you can just use

```
with open("student.csv") as f:
       print("I will do some Magic with this")
```

If the file does not exist you will still get an `FileNotFoundErorr`

example:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'student1.csv'
```

Comment: Suggestion: f.close() in a finally block?

Comment: Even better: `with open('student.csv') as f:` and the file will close after the with block without having to add a `close()`.

Answer (score 2):

USe `exception handling`:-

```
try:
    file = open('student.csv')
except Exception as e:
    print('File not found. Check the name of file.')
```